# How to call the Keras flow_from_directory() method on Test Dataset?

Tags: keras

In the [following article](https://mc.ai/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow_from_directory-and-generators/) there is an instruction that dataset needs to be divided into train, validation and test folders where the test folder should not contain the labeled subfolders. Instead it should only contain a single folder (i.e. Test_folder).

When I use the following code, I get the output message refering that no image were found.

```
Ver.1:
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset\\test\\test_folder\\",
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=10)

Output message: "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.".
```

Instead, if I use the same folder structure (dataset\test\class_a\test_1.jpg etc) as in the train and validation folders, everything seems to be OK and I manage to evaluate my model.

```
Ver.2:
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset\\test\\",
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False,
    seed=10)

Output message: "Found 1500 images belonging to 3 classes.".
```

I also tried the [recommendation](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/loading-unlabeled-images-with-imagedatagenerator-flowfromdirectory-keras) where 'classes' attribute is specified but still 0 images were found.

```
Ver.3:
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset2\\test\\test_folder\\",
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=1,
    classes=['test'],
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=10)

Output message: Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

Thus, what is the correct way to call flow_from_directory() method and why am I getting the message that no files were found? Is my model not correctly evaluated when I use the Ver.2 solution?

Answer (score 3):

> If None, no labels are returned (the generator will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use with model.predict_generator()). Please note that in case of class_mode None, the data still needs to reside in a subdirectory of directory for it to work correctly.

Note that evaluation needs labels in order to determine how good the model is. Typically one only uses no labels in production, or real life testing. You seem to want to test your model, so you actually want to have labels. This means you should sort your testing data

```
train/
    label1/
        ...
        ...
    label2/
        ...
        ...
val/
    label1/
        ...
        ...
    label2/
        ...
        ...
test/
    label1/
        ...
        ...
    label2/
```

Reading documentation is often more helpful than those articles when you want to learn how to use a framework. Here is the link to `flow_from_directory`: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory.

---

On another note, mc.ai is a website full of ripped Medium articles and should be avoided. Many articles are incomplete + it infringes the copyright of the authors.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the structure of your test directory. Try this
[image: Directory structure]

```
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
        target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
        batch_size= batch_size ,shuffle=False,
        class_mode= 'binary',classes=['.'])
```

`classes=['.']` needs to be specified as the `flow_from_directory` method will search for folders.

In your `Ver.3:` you specified the class but there is no folder having `test` inside the directory so you got 0 images and 1 classes.

Comment: Specifying `classes=['.']` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to set as a directory for the flow from directory function the parent folder of the test directory, and to set the classes attribute to the name of the test folder containing the images (here in the example 'test')

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
# In ./dataset directory, there is `test` directory.
test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory('./dataset', classes=['test'])
```

Here's the reference: https://velog.io/@jhcho/Loading-Unlabeled-Images-with-ImageDataGenerator-flowfromdirectory-in-Keras